# This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Twitterizer2.Asynchronous' or one of
>   its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

But I've deleted the twitterizer2.Asynchronous library from my references so why does it still have a problem with it?

This works in my other projects so I don't see what the problem is? It did give me the same error with a Telerik library earlier so I'm thinking it's not specific to Twitterizer.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?  When you compile?  At runtime?  If the latter, can you show the code?

Comment: Sounds like a case of your project's target being .NET 3.5 and Telerik/Twitterizer being .NET 4

Comment: I understand there may be a difference in versions - but I've removed the reference and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *guess* is that one of the assemblies you're still referring to depends on that assembly... so it's still trying to load it.

You might want to use [Fusion Logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to find out why it's being loaded. (More context in the question would help *us* to diagnose it too...)

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the dll's that you're no longer referencing.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I removed the reference of .NET 4.0 project from my .NET 2.0 project and then deleted the DLL of 4.0 project from my bin. Only then my application worked. Thanks.