# "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I'm getting the error: "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

I have a .NET 4.0 dll project that is being called by a .NET 2.0 project.  Is there a way to reconcile the difference in framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913074/this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runtime-and)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> I have a .NET 4.0 dll project that is being called by a .NET 2.0 project. Is there a way to reconcile the difference in framework?

Not that way round, no. The .NET 4 CLR can load .NET 2 assemblies (usually - there are a few exceptions for mixed-mode assemblies, IIRC), but not vice versa.

You'll either have to upgrade the .NET 2 project to .NET 4, or downgrade the .NET 4 project to .NET 3.5 (or earlier).

Answer (score 14):

If you have already tried all the other logical solutions on this page, then double check this.  In my app.config I had a reference to an old framework.

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

should have been

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

The project tab correctly showed v4.0 but the app.config was not committed to our repo with that change.  To fix it, I changed the framework to something else and back to 4.0 again, which updated my app.config file.

Answer (score 10):

I got same error message. I was giving

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
>   "C:\MyService\MyService.exe"

Instead of

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
>   "C:\MyService\MyService.exe"

Comment: This worked, thanks! The error actually points out that the Installutil that we use does not match with the .Net framework version that is V4.0 or higher. In my case, I used installutil of v2.0.50727 when I got the error, and using v4.0.30319 solved it!

Answer (score 6):

Since only one version of the run-time can be loaded into a process (although, as others have alluded, backwards loading - 4.0 loading 2.0 - is okay), you have a few options:

- Upgrade the .Net 2.0 project
- Wrap the .Net 2.0 project (if the source is not yours)
- Downgrade the .Net 4.0 project
- Load the .Net 4.0 project into it's own process (I believe this can work - but will take a bit of effort, IMO)

Answer (score 5):

> You'll either have to upgrade the .NET 2 project to .NET 4, or downgrade the .NET 4 project to .NET 3.5 (or earlier).

How do you upgrade the .net version? I am not sure where to and what to specify. Please help.

Edit:
I found the answer myself. Select the project,  right click and choose Property Pages. There you can select framework version. or select the project and click **Shift+F4**

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, I kept getting that error. What fixed it for me was creating a config called *gacutil.exe.config* in the same directory as gacutil.exe. The config content (a text file) were:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?> <configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup> </configuration>
```

I'm posting this here for reference and ask if anyone knows what's actually happening under the hood. I'm not claiming this is the "proper" way of doing it

Comment: Basically forcing gacutil.exe to run under .NET 4.0. But all gacutil is generally used for is to allow you to register assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Change **`INSTALL_UTIL_HOME`** directory from **`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0`** to **`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`** for installing the service. This error mainly occurs for version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error too, but my problem was that I was using an older version of `GACUTIL.EXE`.

Once I had the correct `GACUTIL` for the latest `.NET` version installed, it worked fine.

The error is misleading because it makes it look like it's the DLL you're trying to register that incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This error may also be triggered by having the wrong .NET framework version selected as the default in IIS.

Click on the root node under the *Connections* view (on the left hand side), then select *Change .NET Framework Version* from the *Actions* view (on the right hand side), then select the appropriate .NET version from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to the way that I configured the Application Pool in IIS.

My web service uses an Application Tool configured for v2.0.50727.  This resulted in the error message.

When I changed it to v4.0.30319, I did not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed the .Net frame work version of the App pool in which the particular project was hosted, I was able to resolve this particular issue.

App pool -> advanced settings -> .Net frame work version (changed v2.0 to v4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Its .net Version mismatch of the dll so try changing to   from  in app.config or web.config.
Generally have a higher Framework than lower because when we add system's dll to the lower version built .net application so it won't work therefore just change to the higher version