# Bamboo MsBuild .Net Framework 2.0

Tags: build, msbuild, .net-2.0, bamboo

My project is .Net Framework 2.0 and I am use Visual Studio 2012. My project build success at my local but project is build error at bamboo server

[image]

> Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized. 
>   MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0,
>   inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use version 4 of MSBuild in the "Executable" option as this determines the version of MSBuild tools used to compile the application. Do not confuse this with the version of the .NET framework you are targetting, which is controlled by your project files.

Comment: Thanks. I have a problem Build project " LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.'"

Comment: New questions should not really go into comments. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607095/this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runtime-and