# Bamboo Build .Net Framework 2.0

Tags: msbuild, .net-2.0, bamboo

My project failed to build on Bamboo server, but my project successfully built on my local machine. My project is using the .Net Framework 2.0.

Error:

> LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.' [C:\Atlassian\Bamboo-Home\xml-data\build-dir\23822338\OCODEA-MER-JOB1\BACKOFFICE\example.csproj]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to build .net 2 with msbuild from .net 4. Are you sure there is .net 2 on the bamboo agent? and it would probably help if you build it with msbuild 2.0. That whay you know for sure the frameworks there. For sinplicity.

Comment: Yes, with msbuild 2.0 "Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized. MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033564/bamboo-msbuild-net-framework-2-0/35033703?noredirect=1#comment57797278_35033703