# Using command to add an external DLL file as "Reference" in a .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, command-line-interface

I have a solution of 7 projects. I have also an external DLL that I can add through Visual Studio :

[image]

It works fine with Visual Studio.
I tried to simulate the same action using command line and namely Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "D:\ExternalDlls\Scorm.dll"
```

I got this error :

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\ExternalDlls\Scorm.dll' or one of its de This assembly is
>   built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot
>   be loaded. At line:1 char:9
>   + Add-Type <<<<   -Path "D:\ExternalDlls\Scorm.dll"
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], BadImageFormatException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand�

My environment is :

- Visual Studio 2015 (it makes things done but I need the CLI )
- Windows 7 - Service Pack1
- Powershell

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify which .NET framework version you are using? 
This error "**This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded**" could also be possible if there is a mismatch in .NET version.

Please refer the following reference:
["This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607095/this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runtime-and)

One more possibility is that there might be other dependent dlls will be there which we need to load also.

Thanks,